# HTML page looks like loading after javascript run. Why initial HTML for h1 has style for color=orange but never observed on the page during load?

Tags: javascript, html

I expect below codes loads a page displaying "Orange Color" and after 5 seconds updates it as "Blue Color", but unfortunately page loads only with "Blue Color". If I uncomment alert it shows first "Orange Color". Why this happening ?

```js
wait(5000);

console.log("Exercise 001");

const updatedH1 = document.querySelectorAll('h1');

updatedH1.forEach(itemx => {

  itemx.style.color = 'blue';

  itemx.innerText = 'Blue Color';

});

function wait(ms) {

  let start = new Date().getTime();

  let end = start;

  while (end < start + ms) {

    end = new Date().getTime();

  }

}
```

```css
.err {
  padding: 10px;
  color: crimson;
  border: 1px dotted crimson;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="page-title" style="color: orange;">Orange Color</h1>

  <!-- <script>
            alert('Hello, world');
        </script> -->
  <script src="roza.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That approach to a `wait()` function is really a bad practice. Try just using a `setTimeout`. Also is there any ajax content being loaded that isn't shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a customize wait function here. **There is a built-in method for this case named `setTimeout` which is a web browser API That sets a timer and executes a function within it after that timer gets exhausted.**

So your final code should be something like this:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("Exercise 001");

  const updatedH1 = document.querySelectorAll('h1');

  updatedH1.forEach(itemx => {

    itemx.style.color = 'blue';

    itemx.innerText = 'Blue Color';

  });
}, 5000)
```

```css
.err {
  padding: 10px;
  color: crimson;
  border: 1px dotted crimson;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="page-title" style="color: orange;">Orange Color</h1>

  <!-- <script>
        alert('Hello, world');
    </script> -->
  <script src="roza.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**NOTE:** You can read more about `setTimeout` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout).

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but I am not clear on why wait function didn't work as expected(and when I enable(uncomment) alert in HTML it works as expected).

Comment: @Elias This is not very complicated, the alert function is a web API, so whenever you uncomment it, this will prevent your script from running synchronously, so your code won't run until you close the alert. You can learn more about web API's [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Introduction).

Comment: @Elias The `wait` function is not a really good practice because it will block your execution runtime since javascript is a single thread language so your code will eat a huge amount of ram (because your while gonna took so long). So it's better to use native API's like `setTimeout`.

Comment: sorry to understand better due to I am new bee in JS: as I know HTML code is executed/rendered from top to bottom regardless of my javascript(because it is last body tag). So if it rendered this way why I don't observe "Orange Color" h1 if I use wait function. Is HTML rendering in sequence or not? thnks

Answer (score 0):

I would really recommend using setTimeout over the while loop you created.

```js
window.setTimeout(() => {
  const updatedH1 = document.querySelectorAll("h1");

  updatedH1.forEach(itemx => {
    itemx.style.color = "blue";

    itemx.innerText = "Blue Color";
  });
  console.log("Exercise 001");
}, 3000);
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="page-title" style="color: orange;">Orange Color</h1>

    <!-- <script>
        alert('Hello, world');
    </script> -->
    <script src="roza.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```